# Muting Media Player at certain points in the Game

Tags: java, android, audio

Hello: I want to be able to leave the option of muting in the below code; The sound plays every time someone gets it correct and when one gets it wrong.

How can i mute this ? Currently the voice is on even when my phone voice is muted. Thanks in advance.

```
if (enteredAnswer == answer) {              
     MediaPlayer mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.correct);
     mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setVolume(float, float)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setVolume(float,%20float)):

> Sets the volume on this player. This API is recommended for balancing
>   the output of audio streams within an application. Unless you are
>   writing an application to control user settings, this API should be
>   used in preference to setStreamVolume(int, int, int) which sets the
>   volume of ALL streams of a particular type. Note that the passed
>   volume values are raw scalars in range 0.0 to 1.0. UI controls should
>   be scaled logarithmically.

To mute the MediaPlayer you need to pass 0:

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
```

To restore the full volume you need to pass 1:

```
mediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
```